# dynamic fill out page with ajax, php js and html?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Suppose you have something like this
HTML FILE:

```
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="my_personal_div">
  </div>
</body>
```

Javascript FILE:

```
    $.(document).ready(){
    $.ajax({
       url:/any_php.php,
       ...
       ...
       if (msg){
         $("#my_personal_div").html(msg);
       }
    });
```

My any_php.php File:

```
echo "<img src=any_image.jpg />"
```

So the Idea is to have a Dynamic div into a html fill it out with some php content created by me, so I can feed multiple htmls with that div at once.  What would be the problem of all this???? any cons??? any Huge security problem?, any better way to have a complete personal feeding, I mean, because I can puy there image, inputs, text, images, etc whatever I want from the php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cons is that it will make **one more** http request each time, and that takes time... And resources.

So it's a good way if you just have to change something on the page without reloading all the page.

A good way of practicing this also is when the user want to change page instead of reloading the all page just loading the content that had changed and using the push state on the browser to indicate that it's a new page. For example the website http://gizmodo.com/ use this.

No problem on the side of security by the way, it's just like loading a new page.

Comment: I don't see that method much used in the site you suggested. Indeed, http://kotaku.com and http://www.devthought.com/ are both good examples, which use AJAX practically for every request.
Not to mention Google or Facebook, of course.

Comment: example of ajax to load content and push state : when you switch page, and again it's just an example, tons of them exists!

Comment: @MarcoGamba By the way, Google and Facebook don't use any jQuery. So not a good example if you look at the question ;)

Comment: Well, just because i didn't see any AJAX in gizmodo (or at least it wasn't evident, I dint't look at the source) I posted a few notable examples (Kotaku even shows a loader when loading a new article), the first sites that came to mind. I know that there are tons of them, but since your site wasn't explanatory enough, I though to post a better example.
Also, the question itself asked for a way to **dynamic fill out page with ajax, php js and html**, not necessarily with jQuery. It is his code to be written in jQuery, but he didn't ask for that.
And I didn't exactly 'mention' them ;)

Comment: Just try to switch to another page on Gizmodo then ;)

Comment: Yay, now I get it! We wasn't talking about the same site! When i visited your link, I was immediately redirected to the localized version of the website (for example, see http://www.gizmodo.co.uk/), which does not use AJAX at all.
And, guess what? Gizmodo and Kotaku are both operated by Gawker, in fact they use the same theme (and same AJAX). So we just misunderstood each other: I didn't know your website and you didn't know mine, but we were trying to explain the same. If I'd seen your website before, I wouldn't even have commented. It's alright :)

Comment: It's ok no problem i didn't know that Gizmodo had a UK version as well. Yes that seemed weird to me as well because you showed an example : Kotaku that used the same system :D. No Problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

**You have to make sure** that the requests (GET and POST) are filtered by the php file you're accessing.
If you don't do that anyone could run code that can harm your site (like SQL-Injections) just by modifying the request.
Same goes for any other php script, so it's nothing really specific to ajax.

Anyways what do you want to create?
A div that randomly shows some content each visit?
Will it change after some seconds and show other content even if the user hasn't reloaded the page?

If you just want to randomly show some content you could do it without having to use ajax.
Same goes if you just want to show some text inside a div.

Using ajax causes more connections which can end in a lot more stress for your server, depending on how much you use it.